# Trouble installing discord.py 1.0

Tags: python, python-3.6, pythonista, discord.py

I am trying to install discord.py 1.0 in pythonista on my iPad with StaSh and so far, nothing that I have found on the internet has worked. Please don’t tell me that this question is a clone of this one [How to install discord.py rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50686388/8116739) because I have already tried that answer and it didn’t work. (`pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]` gives me an error that says `usage: pip.py [-h] [--verbose] sub-command ...
pip.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -U`) Is there any way that I could manually install it without pip or something because it has been being a real pain lately.

P.S. I would also really like to install the version with voice support. I haven’t been able to do that with any version of discord.py at all on my iPad.

Comment: Try upgrading your pip installation first `pip install --upgrade pip`.  `-U` is the short version of the `--upgrade` flag, so see if the long version is available.  If you can't get that to work, run `pip uninstall discord.py` if it's installed, then run the command you have without the `-U`

Comment: I couldn’t run pip install —upgrade pip because it said that —upgrade was an unrecognized argument. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling like you said at the end but it gave me this error “stash: <class ‘ValueError’>: too many values to unpack (expected 2)”

Comment: It sounds like you're using a really old version of pip.  What version of Python are you using? Try running `python3 -m pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]`.  It may be that your system `pip` is an older python2 installation.

Comment: I’m using StaSh 0.7.0 to do this in pythonista. I’m running the StaSh script with python 3.6.

Comment: Please try removing the argument given and only the link to the git repository of the source.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick!

```
pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py#egg=discord.py[voice]
```

This will go to the `rewrite` branch of the `discord.py` depository and will also install the egg file(voice module).

Answer (score 0):

you could just do
`pip install discord`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install discord` or maybe try `apt-get install discord`

Comment: This should rather be a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a similar issue to one I had once

When I tried to run discord.py on an i386 based CPU it wouldn't work due to incompatibilities. I think you may have a similar issue. If you are attempting to run discord.py on an older system it may not be compatible with the CPU arch.

Another thing is that I have seen a lot of answers saying to use the command:

> pip install discord

Instead use:

> pip install discord.py

Answer (score 0):

try going to your text editors terminal and type in `pip install discord` or `pip install discord.py`

alternatively, you can try `python3 -m pip install -U discord.py`

originally I had trouble installing from `cmd`, this method helped me a lot. However if you are using PyCharm you can go to `python packages` and install `discord.py`

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this in terminal

```
pip install discord
```

or
python3 -m pip install discord

if version is earlier then do like this

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade discord
```

or

```
pip install --upgrade discord
```