# How to create role with variable name in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I have been trying to make a verify command (.verify), where it needs an argument names and is supposed to make a role with their name and assign it to them and also is in supposed to be sent in a specific channel so the people aren't allowed to make roles themselves I thought it was the channel.id at first but I put print(ctx.message.channel.id) and it was the same so I knew that wasn't the error, but it doesn't make the role and doesn't give any role, and even no error! Please help me. Here is my code so far.

```
    @client.command(pass_context=True)
    async def verify(ctx, name):
      print(ctx.message.channel.id)
      if ctx.message.channel.id == 521645091098722305:
        await client.create_role(author.server, name=name)
        await client.say('Done! Welcome!')
```

If done thanks,
Sincerely,
Bread

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?  If you're using 0.16, also called the async branch, then all ids are strings, so you should be checking `if ctx.message.channel.id == '521645091098722305'` instead

Comment: I pretty sure I'm using the latest, because I just updated it a week or two ago. But I'll try anyways

Comment: Try `import discord; print(discord.__version__)`.  To install the rewrite branch, follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686388/how-to-install-discord-py-rewrite

Comment: Thank you so much! I just changed it to a string and it made an error saying an error about author.server and then i changed it do ctx.message.author.server and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Now I need to be able to add the role that was just created. My idea was 
    await client.add_roles(ctx.message.author, name=name)
but i had an error saying
    TypeError: add_roles() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'

Comment: `create_role` will return a `Role` object.  Capture that and pass it to `add_roles`

Comment: I tried using this
                `role = discord.utils.get(member.server.roles, name=name)`
                `await client.add_roles(ctx.message.author, role)`
but it just says member is not defined.

Comment: `member` isn't defined.  You could use `ctx.server.roles` instead

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'server'

Comment: Try `ctx.message.server.roles` then.

Comment: Now it has a python extension problem :/
 File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2915, in <genexpr>
    new_roles = utils._unique(role.id for role in itertools.chain(member.roles, roles))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Use strings instead of integers for ids in the async branch.  You also need to capture the `Role` that `create_role` makes, and pass that to `add_roles`

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def verify(ctx, name):
  print(ctx.message.channel.id)
  if ctx.message.channel.id == '521645091098722305:
    role = await client.create_role(ctx.message.author.server, name=name)
    await client.add_roles(ctx.message.author, role)
    await client.say('Done! Welcome!')
```

The equivalent rewrite command would be

```
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx, name):
  print(ctx.channel.id)
  if ctx.channel.id == 521645091098722305:
    role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name=name)
    await ctx.message.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send('Done! Welcome!')
```

Comment: I tried installing rewrite branch but it says 
`warning: templates not found in C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/git-core/templates
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Command "git clone -q https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rtw2c0xr\discord.py" failed with error code 128 in None`

Comment: Try `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]`

Comment: Yep, installed it, but now some of my other commands aren't working. Should this happen?

Comment: The rewrite branch is a breaking change, so if you want to migrate your code you'll likely need to change some of it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html

Comment: I use a logs_from in my clear command, the usage in the migration site doesn't make sense to me. How would I change it?
    `@client.command()
    async def clear(ctx, amount=100):
        channel = ctx.message.channel
        messages = []
        async for message in logs_from(channel, limit=int(amount)):
            messages.append(message)
        await message.delete(message)
        await TextChannel.delete_messages(messages)
        await client.say('Messages deleted')`
sorry if you can't read it I'm new to this

Comment: Use `await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))` instead

Comment: Back to normal conversation, for client.create_role, it says command doesn't exist so I changed it to guild.create_role which was noted in the migration site, but it said guild is not defined. Do I put guild in the attributes or?

Comment: I just realised that it only supports one word, I tried making it support two word but it makes two roles, one with the first name and the other with the last name. (Some peoples names could be 3 words or 4 words.) I used this setup
`async def verify(ctx, *args):
    print(ctx.message.channel.id)
    name = ' '
    for word in args:
        name += word
        name += ' '`

Comment: Use the keyword only argument syntax: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments