# How to add a reason in Audit Log on user kick/ban?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am programming a discord BOT in Python and I an working on a kick and ban command. I'm trying to make the BOT change the Audit Log of the server to add a "With reason: " to add the responsible moderator. Do anyone know how I can do that (like in this [image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjRpNv9yNHfAhXE34UKHbrUDRUQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdiscordia.me%2Faudit-logs&psig=AOvVaw3GZuPp4doQIZGLn-Pcp9yd&ust=1546603450255197)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `discord.py rewrite` you can use [the ban coroutine](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.ban)

`ban(user, *, reason=None, delete_message_days=1)`

where the reason is :

`reason (Optional[str]) – The reason the user got banned.`

Comment: [The kick command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.kick) The documentation is a good source of information

Comment: Something similar, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50686388/how-to-install-discord-py-rewrite